# How to update Rundeck project setting using CLI

Tags: rundeck

I want  update project settings for existing Rundeck Project. For example : add resources / nodes to the Rundeck project using CLI. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Below is the command using Rundeck CLI to add a resource file in .xml format to an existing Rundeck project

$ rd projects configure set -p MG-Test-CLI -- 
--resources.source.1.config.file="/home/rundeck/iidas/resources.xml" \ --resources.source.1.config.generateFileAutomatically=true 
--resources.source.1.config.includeServerNode=true 
--resources.source.1.type=file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Here more useful Rundeck CLI project commands:

```
# create project
rd projects create -p project1

# get project configuration
rd projects configure get -p project1

# Configure nodes from remote URL (GitLab)
rd projects configure update -p project1 -- \
  --resources.source.1.type=url \
  --resources.source.1.config.url='https://git.i.example.com/api/v4/projects/3/repository/files/project1%2Fdev%2Fnodes.json/raw?ref=master&private_token=1234567890' \
  --resources.source.1.config.timeout=10 \
  --resources.source.1.config.cache=false
```

See also [Rundeck CLI documentation](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/commands/) and [project parameter](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#project-properties).